# is there is any IDE or GUI available to work with CASSANDRA DATABASE with PHP?

Tags: php, cassandra

we are doing project currently on php and we want to use cassandra no sql database and is there is any API available like MYSQL,LAMP?

Comment: You are asking for three entirely different things: an IDE, a GUI, and an API. Which one do you mean? :)

Answer (score 3):

Plenty, but this has been answered before: [Cassandra PHP module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508649/cassandra-php-module)

SimpleCassie and Thrift seem to be common.

(These are API's, a GUI or IDE would be hard to find.)