# is any simple web project using cassandra and php available?

Tags: php, facebook, cassandra

We are doing project using PHP and Cassandra. If any already finished a project using PHP and Cassandra, that is available means that will helpful for reference. Is there is any sample project available? And Facebook uses Cassandra - can we get some inputs from Facebook experience and tools? Is Facebook maintain as opened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508649/cassandra-php-module

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples Does that help?